# How to make 2 elements out of 1 during a map with Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, lodash

I have an array of of objects say:

```
let array = [{x: 3}, {x: 4}, {x: 5}];
```

I want to map it and add new element after each existing one. So to keep it simple I'd like to get:

```
let mappedArray = [{x: 3}, {y: 3}, {x: 4}, {y: 4}, {x: 5}, {y: 5}];
```

It can be done with flatten like this:

```
let mappedAray = _(array)
    .map(obj => {return [obj, {y: obj.x}]})
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

But I'm wondering maybe there is a more elegant solution. Some kind of oneliner method that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` in plain javascript.

```js
let array = [{x: 3}, {x: 4}, {x: 5}];
var result = array.reduce((r, e) => (r.push(e, {y: e.x}), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `Array.prototype.forEach()` and `Array.prototype.push()` functions:

```js
var arr = [{x: 3}, {x: 4}, {x: 5}], result = [];

arr.forEach(function(o){ result.push(o, {y: o.x}) });    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just use Object.assign?

```js
let array = [{x: 3}, {x: 4}, {x: 5}];
let mappedArray = [{x: 3}, {y: 3}, {x: 4}, {y: 4}, {x: 5}, {y: 5}];

const mapArray = (a, b) => Object.assign([],a,b);

console.log(mapArray(array,mappedArray));
```